# My UV won't bake properly, did I miss any step?

Tags: rendering, uv, texture-baking, baking

1. UV unwrap low poly
2. Add Material
3. Shading Mode, added image texture(created a new image) and normal map nodes
4. Render properties -> cycles -> baking -> bake type :normal -> selected to active -> bake
5. and this is the result

I also try using an add-on, and it's all the same. Did I miss any steps?
It was working fine last week for me, but I tried to bake a few things today and it all have similar issues.

[image: I'm trying to bake the normal from left cube to right]

Comment: Hello, are you trying to bake the slots? If the faces of the high poly are completely perpendicular to the baking faces, nothing will be baked. Is it your problem here?

Comment: Oh! I'm new, I actually didn't know that the faces of the high poly won't be baked if it's perpendicular to the baking face. Let me try this out once again with something else. Thanks!

Comment: yes because baking the normals save the faces direction, if the face that you're trying to bake is parallel to the ray (i.e. perpendicular to the baking face), it won't save anything (same thing if the ray is perpendicular to the face)

Comment: thank you so much! I tried adjust the faces and stuff and it works like charm now

Answer (score 0):

Baking the normals save the faces direction, if the face that you're trying to bake is parallel to the ray (i.e. perpendicular to the baking face), it won't save anything (same thing if the ray is perpendicular to the face). The solution is to tilt a bit all the faces you want to bake.